# Webdriver cannot connect to Selenium server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am currently trying to set up webdriver and selenium together to run my automation tests through docker but am facing issues. Each time i try to run the tests I get the following error `ERROR wdio-runner: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444`

I am using the selenium/standalone-chrome from docker and can see that the server is configured correctly and running at 127.0.0.1:4444 as I can hit it.

When I try to run webdriver however I seem to face the issue mentioned above. I believe the issue must be something in my webdriver config but having followed the documentation I can't see what's wrong...

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiWebdriver = require('chai-webdriverio').default;
const debug = process.env.DEBUG;

exports.config = {
  runner: 'local',
  host: '127.0.0.1', 
  port: 4444, 
  path: '/wd/hub',
  specs: ['specs/**/*.js'],
  suites: {
    smoke: ['specs/smoke-spec.js']
  },
  maxInstances: 10,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {}
  },
  sync: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  coloredLogs: true,
  deprecationWarnings: false,
  bail: 0,
  debug,
  execArgv: debug ? ['--inspect'] : [],
  screenshotOnReject: true,
  screenshotPath: './error-screenshots',
  baseUrl: https://localhost:443,
  waitforTimeout: 30000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  seleniumLogs: './selenium-logs',
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: [
    [
      'allure',
      {
        outputDir: 'test-output',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false
      }
    ],
    ['spec', {}]
  ],
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 400000,
    compilers: ['js:babel-register']
  },
  before() {
    chai.use(chaiWebdriver(browser));
    global.expect = chai.expect;
  },
  afterTest: test => {
    if (!test.passed) {
      browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
  }
};
```